# Since Library is deprecated, how should I go about embedding my Assistant with hotword capabilities?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Until recently, I used Google Assistant Library’s hotword Assistant to embed it into a raspberry Pi, mostly due to it’s hotword capabilities. I've done quite a few tweaks to make it work in a bigger project and add some functionalities to it.

Since now deprecated, I checked through the Service part of the actions SDK to make something similar, but ended up not finding what I wanted : the hotword part. I tried with the pushtotalk.py code but it seems way more complicated than the hotword.py, and of course does not have hotword capabilities on its own. 
I tried snowboy, but for other reasons not related this is not a possibility.
Also, I tried to contact the support concerning the deprecation (how long will they support it/is there an alternative), but they sent me here.

So here is my question : is there a way to trigger the pushtotalk.py with a hotword/programmatically with an event ? (Ideally I would like to trigger it via a WebSocket event)
Also, is there any information concerning the deprecation of the Google Assistant Library part that I did not find on the Internet ?

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I also want hotword capability on Google Assistant Service.